# Minimum value of $\operatorname{rank} (A+B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $m \times n$ matrices. What is the minimum value of $\operatorname{rank} (A+B)$? And how do you deduce that minimum value?

Edit:
I'm specifically looking for case where $rank(A) \neq rank(B)$

Comment: Hint: what happens if $B = -A$?

Comment: @Bruno B that's a very specific case, I'm looking for a more general expression in terms Rank(A) and Rank(B)

Comment: If $B$ has entries that are sufficiently small, then $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\geq \operatorname{rank}(A)$. Otherwise not much else can be said about the minimum if we don't make further assumptions on either $A$ or $B$.